# SQL Server collation: lowercase preference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

I have SQL Server 2008 and was looking for collation with lowercase preference for case sensitive characters and wasn't able to find any!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

So, is there any CS collation with lowercase preference?

Comment: No. Collations are either case sensitive or not. There is no upper/lower case collation. I don't even understand what a case sensitive collation with preference for lower case even means, unless you are talking about sort order (lower case letters before upper case).

Comment: Wow, thanks for fast answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

Collations are either case sensitive (CS) or not (CI).

There is no upper/lower case collation.

I don't even understand what a case sensitive collation with preference for lower case even means, unless you are talking about sort order (lower case letters before upper case), but even so, this is not possible with the existing collations.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I mean lower case letters before upper case. Than I consider question closed; The only way to have lowercase letters before uppercase is to use case insensitive collation.

Comment: @Kitamo - You may be able to do that in the application, but not in SQL Server, as far as I know.

Comment: As I am using java, it is possible using Comparator object or Comparable interface to sort data as I need, but it will bring heavy performance overhead on application server if data requested often.

Comment: @Kitamo - Still, not something you can do in the DB.

Comment: Well, I use on SQL Server default SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation. So when I execute SELECT with ORDER BY  - lowercase letters appear before uppercase(EXAMPLE: 'aCompany' appears before 'ACompany').

Comment: @Kitamo - That would be how the collation is defined. My point was more that you can't specify whether upper or lower case comes first. You can only use what is there.